# How do I setup a python, telnet proxy for a device on a different network over SSH?

Tags: python, proxy, ssh, telnet

## Overview:

I have a device sitting on a local network to a computer that is sitting on an outside network.  I would like to create a software program that allows me to seamlessly connect to the device from a computer on a different network.  For purposes of this question, I've created a picture to help describe the network flow.  What I need help with is what python packages I would need to develop the solution for this problem.

## Details:

I have a computer MYPC (IP address 192.168.0.168) that is attached to the internet running through a proxy server (ROUTER1).  I have full control over MYPC's environment, which is running Linux.

I have a second computer SOMESERVER (IP address 192.168.1.168) that is attached to the internet running through a proxy server (ROUTER2).  In addition, SOMESERVER (IP address 10.0.0.159) is also attached to a local network (LOCAL).  SOMESERVER is running windows.  I have very limited control with SOMESERVER: I am able to send an executable to SOMESERVER that can run once before it is removed.  I do not know the internet/world IP address of the ROUTER2 initially.

I have a device (DEVICE1) attached to SOMESERVER through LOCAL (IP address: 10.0.0.157).
I have another device (DEVICE2) attached to SOMESERVER through LOCAL (IP address: 10.0.0.158).  DEVICE(x) runs linux.  I have python on DEVICE(x) and I could install a pure python package if I needed to.  However, I do not have the ability to compile for DEVICE(x).

I can connect between SOMESERVER and MYPC through the internet using SSH over ROUTER1 and ROUTER2.  I can connect between SOMESERVER and DEVICE1 through the local network (LOCAL) using Telnet.  I can connect between SOMESERVER and DEVICE2 through the local network (LOCAL) using Telnet.

I want to send a program to SOMESERVER that allows me seamless access over SSH and Telnet to DEVICE1 and DEVICE2 from MYPC.  In addition, I want that program to be running python.

Here's a picture that helps explain the above problem: 
[image: Visual Explanation of the Problem]

## Solution:

What I think I want is as follows.  I need help with the details and what packages I might need to make it happen.

### Part 1: The Dial Home Client and Server

Create a "dial home" server program (DIAL_HOME_SERVER) for MYPC which listens for any one dialing home and then will "dial into" any SOMESERVER that "dials home" using SSH.

Create a "dial home" client program (DIAL_HOME_CLIENT) for SOMESERVER which is downloaded as part of a package

### Part 2: The Proxy Server

Create a ssh to telnet proxy server program (PROXY_SERVER) for SOMESERVER which listens for connections from MYPC and funnels them into a telnet connection to DEVICE(x).

Thanks to [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill), it sounds like I can use [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to pull together the PROXY_SERVER code on SOMESERVER.  It appears that Paramiko also requires [PyCryto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/), and the Windows binary for it can be found [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml).

### Future Robustness

At a future date, the telnet connection will be replaced with an SSH client (dropbox on DEVICE(x)).

### In Closing

I think the above will allow MYPC to connect "seamlessly", but the details of how to put together these programs is unknown to me.  I already know how to package up a python program using Innosetup and/or py2exe.  What I'd love to see is links pointing to different pieces of the solution so I can pull it all together.  And then I can post it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I didn't quite follow all of your description, especially the "dial home" client/server part. However, your diagram seems sufficient for understanding.

1. Set up port forwarding on "router2" that forwards the incoming SSH port to your Windows server.
2. Write a Python program (you will probably find [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) helpful) that runs on your Windows server, listens for SSH connections, and opens a telnet connection to one of your devices on the back end.

That seems sufficient to me. If you've got weird restrictions on the Windows server about only being able to run an executable once before it is deleted, that seems like another problem to solve that doesn't really relate to *this* tunnelling problem.

Comment: I will update my original question:  I don't actually know what the IP address is of the server initially until it "dials home" and tells me.  Thanks for the paramiko tip.  I have not officially used that yet on a production system, though I have heard of the package.

Comment: If you need it to dial home - I assume this to mean it doesn't have a static IP - you can use [dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns)